# How to manually patch Blogger template to use Disqus

Tags: comments, blogger, disqus

I'm trying to add disqus to my blog and I tried following this guide to do so:

http://disqus.com/docs/patch-blogger/

However their instructions are completely off with what I have on my custom template.

Here is the template:

http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>

```
<b:skin><![CDATA[/*-----------------------------------------------
```

Blogger Template Style
Name:     Picture Window
Designer: Josh Peterson
URL:      www.noaesthetic.com
----------------------------------------------- */

/* Variable definitions
   ====================
   
   http://themes.googleusercontent.com/image?id=1OACCYOE0-eoTRTfsBuX1NMN9nz599ufI1Jh0CggPFA_sK80AGkIr8pLtYRpNUKPmwtEa) repeat-x fixed top center" value="#9a927f url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/image?id=0BwVBOzw_-hbMODUwNDk4YWQtMjg4NS00MzlmLWJhNzMtYzM5ZmIzYzdkZDRj) no-repeat fixed top center /* Credit: peeterv (http://www.istockphoto.com/googleimages.php?id=2646746&platform=blogger) */"/>

http://www.blogblog.com/1kt/transparent/white80.png) repeat scroll top left"/>

http://www.blogblog.com/1kt/transparent/header_gradient_shade.png)"/>

http://www.blogblog.com/1kt/transparent/tabs_gradient_shade.png)"/>
   http://www.blogblog.com/1kt/transparent/white80.png)" value="url(http://www.blogblog.com/1kt/transparent/tabs_gradient_shade.png)"/>
   http://www.blogblog.com/1kt/transparent/black50.png) repeat scroll top left" value="transparent none no-repeat scroll top left"/>

http://www.blogblog.com/1kt/transparent/white80.png) repeat scroll top left" value="transparent none repeat scroll top center"/>

http://www.blogblog.com/1kt/transparent/black50.png) repeat scroll top left" value="transparent url(http://www.blogblog.com/1kt/transparent/black50.png) repeat scroll top left"/>

*/

/* Content
----------------------------------------------- */
body {
  font: $(body.font);
  color: $(body.text.color);
}

html body .region-inner {
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.content-outer {
  font-size: 90%;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: $(link.color);
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: $(link.visited.color);
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;
  color: $(link.hover.color);
}

.body-fauxcolumn-outer {
  background: $(body.background);
}

.content-outer {
  background: $(content.background);

-moz-border-radius: $(content.border.radius);
  -webkit-border-radius: $(content.border.radius);
  -goog-ms-border-radius: $(content.border.radius);
  border-radius: $(content.border.radius);

-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 $(content.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 $(content.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -goog-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 $(content.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 $(content.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);

margin: $(content.margin) auto;
}

.content-inner {
  padding: $(content.padding);
}

/* Header
----------------------------------------------- */
.header-outer {
  background: $(header.background.color) $(header.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll top left;
  _background-image: none;

color: $(header.text.color);

-moz-border-radius: $(header.border.radius);
  -webkit-border-radius: $(header.border.radius);
  -goog-ms-border-radius: $(header.border.radius);
  border-radius: $(header.border.radius);
}

.Header img, .Header #header-inner {
  -moz-border-radius: $(header.border.radius);
  -webkit-border-radius: $(header.border.radius);
  -goog-ms-border-radius: $(header.border.radius);
  border-radius: $(header.border.radius);
}

.header-inner .Header .titlewrapper,
.header-inner .Header .descriptionwrapper {
  padding-left: $(header.padding);
  padding-right: $(header.padding);
}

.Header h1 {
  font: $(header.font);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.Header h1 a {
  color: $(header.text.color);
}

.Header .description {
  font-size: 130%;
}

/* Tabs
----------------------------------------------- */
.tabs-inner {
  margin: .5em $(tabs.margin.sides) $(tabs.margin.bottom);
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs-inner .section {
  margin: 0;
}

.tabs-inner .widget ul {
  padding: 0;

background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat scroll bottom;

-moz-border-radius: $(tabs.border.radius);
  -webkit-border-radius: $(tabs.border.radius);
  -goog-ms-border-radius: $(tabs.border.radius);
  border-radius: $(tabs.border.radius);
}

.tabs-inner .widget li {
  border: none;
}

.tabs-inner .widget li a {
  display: block;

padding: .5em 1em;
  margin-$endSide: $(tabs.spacing);

color: $(tabs.text.color);
  font: $(tabs.font);

-moz-border-radius: $(tab.border.radius) $(tab.border.radius) 0 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: $(tab.border.radius);
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: $(tab.border.radius);
  -goog-ms-border-radius: $(tab.border.radius) $(tab.border.radius) 0 0;
  border-radius: $(tab.border.radius) $(tab.border.radius) 0 0;

background: $(tab.background);

border-$endSide: 1px solid $(tabs.separator.color);
}

.tabs-inner .widget li:first-child a {
  padding-$startSide: 1.25em;

-moz-border-radius-top$startSide: $(tab.first.border.radius);
  -moz-border-radius-bottom$startSide: $(tabs.border.radius);
  -webkit-border-top-$startSide-radius: $(tab.first.border.radius);
  -webkit-border-bottom-$startSide-radius: $(tabs.border.radius);
  -goog-ms-border-top-$startSide-radius: $(tab.first.border.radius);
  -goog-ms-border-bottom-$startSide-radius: $(tabs.border.radius);
  border-top-$startSide-radius: $(tab.first.border.radius);
  border-bottom-$startSide-radius: $(tabs.border.radius);
}

.tabs-inner .widget li.selected a,
.tabs-inner .widget li a:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

background: $(tabs.selected.background.color) $(tab.selected.background.gradient) repeat scroll bottom;
  color: $(tabs.selected.text.color);

-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -goog-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

/* Headings
----------------------------------------------- */
h2 {
  font: $(widget.title.font);
  text-transform: $(widget.title.text.transform);
  color: $(widget.title.text.color);
  margin: .5em 0;
}

/* Main
----------------------------------------------- */
.main-outer {
  background: $(main.background);

-moz-border-radius: $(main.border.radius.top) $(main.border.radius.top) 0 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: $(main.border.radius.top);
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: $(main.border.radius.top);
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  -goog-ms-border-radius: $(main.border.radius.top) $(main.border.radius.top) 0 0;
  border-radius: $(main.border.radius.top) $(main.border.radius.top) 0 0;

-moz-box-shadow: 0 $(region.shadow.offset) $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 $(region.shadow.offset) $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -goog-ms-box-shadow: 0 $(region.shadow.offset) $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  box-shadow: 0 $(region.shadow.offset) $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.main-inner {
  padding: 15px $(main.padding.sides) 20px;
}

.main-inner .column-center-inner {
  padding: 0 0;
}

.main-inner .column-left-inner {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.main-inner .column-right-inner {
  padding-right: 0;
}

/* Posts
----------------------------------------------- */
h3.post-title {
  margin: 0;
  font: $(post.title.font);
}

.comments h4 {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  font: $(post.title.font);
}

.post-outer {
  background-color: $(post.background.color);
  border: solid 1px $(post.border.color);

-moz-border-radius: $(post.border.radius);
  -webkit-border-radius: $(post.border.radius);
  border-radius: $(post.border.radius);
  -goog-ms-border-radius: $(post.border.radius);

padding: 15px 20px;
  margin: 0 $(post.margin.sides) 20px;
}

.post-body {
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-size: 110%;
}

.post-header {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;

color: $(post.footer.text.color);
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.post-footer {
  margin: .5em 0 0;

color: $(post.footer.text.color);
  line-height: 1.6;
}

## blog-pager {

font-size: 140%
}

## comments .comment-author {

padding-top: 1.5em;

border-top: dashed 1px #ccc;
  border-top: dashed 1px rgba(128, 128, 128, .5);

background-position: 0 1.5em;
}

## comments .comment-author:first-child {

padding-top: 0;

border-top: none;
}

.avatar-image-container {
  margin: .2em 0 0;
}

/* Widgets
----------------------------------------------- */
.widget ul, .widget #ArchiveList ul.flat {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.widget ul li, .widget #ArchiveList ul.flat li {
  border-top: dashed 1px #ccc;
  border-top: dashed 1px rgba(128, 128, 128, .5);
}

.widget ul li:first-child, .widget #ArchiveList ul.flat li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

.widget .post-body ul {
  list-style: disc;
}

.widget .post-body ul li {
  border: none;
}

/* Footer
----------------------------------------------- */
.footer-outer {
  color:$(footer.text.color);
  background: $(footer.background);

-moz-border-radius: $(footer.border.radius.top) $(footer.border.radius.top) $(footer.border.radius.bottom) $(footer.border.radius.bottom);
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: $(footer.border.radius.top);
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: $(footer.border.radius.top);
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: $(footer.border.radius.bottom);
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: $(footer.border.radius.bottom);
  -goog-ms-border-radius: $(footer.border.radius.top) $(footer.border.radius.top) $(footer.border.radius.bottom) $(footer.border.radius.bottom);
  border-radius: $(footer.border.radius.top) $(footer.border.radius.top) $(footer.border.radius.bottom) $(footer.border.radius.bottom);

-moz-box-shadow: 0 $(region.shadow.offset) $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 $(region.shadow.offset) $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -goog-ms-box-shadow: 0 $(region.shadow.offset) $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  box-shadow: 0 $(region.shadow.offset) $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.footer-inner {
  padding: 10px $(main.padding.sides) 20px;
}

.footer-outer a {
  color: $(footer.link.color);
}

.footer-outer a:visited {
  color: $(footer.link.visited.color);
}

.footer-outer a:hover {
  color: $(footer.link.hover.color);
}

.footer-outer .widget h2 {
  color: $(footer.widget.title.text.color);
}
]]>

```
<b:template-skin>
  <b:variable default='930px' name='content.width' type='length' value='930px'/>
  <b:variable default='0' name='main.column.left.width' type='length' value='180px'/>
  <b:variable default='360px' name='main.column.right.width' type='length' value='180px'/>

  <![CDATA[
  body {
    min-width: $(content.width);
  }

  .content-outer, .region-inner {
    min-width: $(content.width);
    max-width: $(content.width);
    _width: $(content.width);
  }

  .main-inner .columns {
    padding-left: $(main.column.left.width);
    padding-right: $(main.column.right.width);
  }

  .main-inner .fauxcolumn-center-outer {
    left: $(main.column.left.width);
    right: $(main.column.right.width);
    /* IE6 does not respect left and right together */
    _width: expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth -
        parseInt("$(main.column.left.width)") -
        parseInt("$(main.column.right.width)") + 'px');
  }

  .main-inner .fauxcolumn-left-outer {
    width: $(main.column.left.width);
  }

  .main-inner .fauxcolumn-right-outer {
    width: $(main.column.right.width);
  }

  .main-inner .column-left-outer {
    width: $(main.column.left.width);
    right: $(main.column.left.width);
    margin-right: -$(main.column.left.width);
  }

  .main-inner .column-right-outer {
    width: $(main.column.right.width);
    margin-right: -$(main.column.right.width);
  }

  #layout {
    min-width: 0;
  }

  #layout .content-outer {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 800px;
  }

  #layout .region-inner {
    min-width: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
  ]]>
</b:template-skin>
```

```
<header>
<div class='header-outer'>
<div class='header-cap-top cap-top'>
  <div class='cap-left'/>
  <div class='cap-right'/>
</div>
<div class='fauxborder-left header-fauxborder-left'>
<div class='fauxborder-right header-fauxborder-right'/>
<div class='region-inner header-inner'>
  <b:section class='header' id='header' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'>
```

```
<div class='tabs-outer'>
<div class='tabs-cap-top cap-top'>
  <div class='cap-left'/>
  <div class='cap-right'/>
</div>
<div class='fauxborder-left tabs-fauxborder-left'>
<div class='fauxborder-right tabs-fauxborder-right'/>
<div class='region-inner tabs-inner'>
  <b:section class='tabs' id='crosscol' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='yes'>
```

```
<div class='main-outer'>
<div class='main-cap-top cap-top'>
  <div class='cap-left'/>
  <div class='cap-right'/>
</div>

<div class='fauxborder-left main-fauxborder-left'>
<div class='fauxborder-right main-fauxborder-right'/>
<div class='region-inner main-inner'>

  <div class='columns fauxcolumns'>

    <div class='fauxcolumn-outer fauxcolumn-center-outer'>
    <div class='cap-top'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    <div class='fauxborder-left'>
    <div class='fauxborder-right'/>
    <div class='fauxcolumn-inner'>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='cap-bottom'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class='fauxcolumn-outer fauxcolumn-left-outer'>
    <div class='cap-top'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    <div class='fauxborder-left'>
    <div class='fauxborder-right'/>
    <div class='fauxcolumn-inner'>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='cap-bottom'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class='fauxcolumn-outer fauxcolumn-right-outer'>
    <div class='cap-top'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    <div class='fauxborder-left'>
    <div class='fauxborder-right'/>
    <div class='fauxcolumn-inner'>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='cap-bottom'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- corrects IE6 width calculation -->
    <div class='columns-inner'>

    <div class='column-center-outer'>
    <div class='column-center-inner'>
      <b:section class='main' id='main' showaddelement='no'>
```

```
    <div class='column-left-outer'>
    <div class='column-left-inner'>
      <aside>
      <macro:include id='main-column-left-sections' name='sections'>
        <macro:param default='0' name='num' value='1'/>
        <macro:param default='sidebar-left' name='idPrefix'/>
        <macro:param default='sidebar' name='class'/>
        <macro:param default='true' name='includeBottom'/>
      </macro:include>
      </aside>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class='column-right-outer'>
    <div class='column-right-inner'>
      <aside>
      <macro:include id='main-column-right-sections' name='sections'>
        <macro:param default='2' name='num' value='1'/>
        <macro:param default='sidebar-right' name='idPrefix'/>
        <macro:param default='sidebar' name='class'/>
        <macro:param default='true' name='includeBottom'/>
      </macro:include>
      </aside>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div style='clear: both'/>
  <!-- columns -->
  </div>

<!-- main -->
</div>
</div>
<div class='main-cap-bottom cap-bottom'>
  <div class='cap-left'/>
  <div class='cap-right'/>
</div>
</div>

<footer>
<div class='footer-outer'>
<div class='footer-cap-top cap-top'>
  <div class='cap-left'/>
  <div class='cap-right'/>
</div>
<div class='fauxborder-left footer-fauxborder-left'>
<div class='fauxborder-right footer-fauxborder-right'/>
<div class='region-inner footer-inner'>
  <macro:include id='footer-sections' name='sections'>
    <macro:param default='2' name='num' value='3'/>
    <macro:param default='footer' name='idPrefix'/>
    <macro:param default='foot' name='class'/>
    <macro:param default='false' name='includeBottom'/>
  </macro:include>
  <!-- outside of the include in order to lock Attribution widget -->
  <b:section class='foot' id='footer-3' showaddelement='no'>
```

document.body.className = document.body.className.replace('loading', '');

```
<macro:if cond='data:col.num &gt;= 2'>
  <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' mexpr:class='&quot;section-columns columns-&quot; + data:col.num'>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class='first columns-cell'>
      <b:section mexpr:class='data:col.class' mexpr:id='data:col.idPrefix + &quot;-2-1&quot;'/>
    </td>

    <td class='columns-cell'>
      <b:section mexpr:class='data:col.class' mexpr:id='data:col.idPrefix + &quot;-2-2&quot;'/>
    </td>

    <macro:if cond='data:col.num &gt;= 3'>
      <td class='columns-cell'>
        <b:section mexpr:class='data:col.class' mexpr:id='data:col.idPrefix + &quot;-2-3&quot;'/>
      </td>
    </macro:if>

    <macro:if cond='data:col.num &gt;= 4'>
      <td class='columns-cell'>
        <b:section mexpr:class='data:col.class' mexpr:id='data:col.idPrefix + &quot;-2-4&quot;'/>
      </td>
    </macro:if>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

  <macro:if cond='data:col.includeBottom'>
    <b:section mexpr:class='data:col.class' mexpr:id='data:col.idPrefix + &quot;-3&quot;' showaddelement='no'/>
  </macro:if>
</macro
```

Comment: Aah! Don't do it! http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/12153020670